# Paging Android Unit Testing PagingData

Tags: android, firebase, android-paging-3

Hello I am trying to unit test the Paging Data I receive from the flow of a Pager.I am using the paging-testing dependency as stated in Paging Testing Android guide. This dependency has a method to convert the PagedData to a list using asSnapshot() method. I have followed the same code as the guide suggested. But my test is completing before I receive the result. I debugged the lambda block which the asSnapshot() takes and it is unreachable.

I am sharing my test code below.

```
    private val repo:ProfileRepository = mock()
    private val fakeRepo = EmployeeTestRepo()
    private val fakeModule = FakeEmployeeModule()
    private val fakeColl = fakeModule.getFakeCollection()
    private val fakeConfig = fakeModule.getFakePagingConfig()
    private val useCase:GetEmployeeRequestsUseCase = GetEmployeeRequestsUseCase(repo,fakeColl,
        fakeConfig)

    @Test
    fun `fetch employee requests from Firestore`() = runTest {
        whenever(repo.getUserRequests(fakeColl,fakeConfig))
            .thenReturn(fakeRepo.getUserRequests(fakeColl,fakeConfig))
        backgroundScope.launch(UnconfinedTestDispatcher(this.testScheduler)) {
            val flow =  useCase.invoke()
            val list = flow.asSnapshot(this@launch){
                appendScrollWhile {  item: User -> item.name == "5 employee request" }
            }
            Assert.assertEquals(list, fakeRepo.getUserRequests(fakeColl, fakeConfig))

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can someone share some insights on this?